# Метод Array.find() выдает undefined при корректно заданных условиях

Tags: javascript, find

Есть некий массив объектов с уникальными `id`:

```
const array = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]];
```

Применяю метод `find` для поиска объекта по уникальному ключу `id`. 
Ответ периодически выдает `undefined`. Не могу понять в чем ошибка.

Ниже указан пример запроса:

```
const oneId = array.find((el) => el.id === Math.ceil(Math.random() * array.length));
```

При этом отдельно

```
Math.ceil(Math.random() * array.length)
```

выдает все корректно (только 1 или 2).

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: На первой итерации, `el` может быть `[{id: 1}]`, а `random()` - 2. В этом и причина.

Comment: Точно, я сразу не сообразила, что random() срабатывает заново на каждом перебираемом элементе. Теперь все понятно. Благодарю за помощь!!!